# Find a word and replacing entire line in a text file

Tags: c, replace, line

I am trying to write some short C code that will find the word "Applicat" and replace that entire line with something else, not just the word.
For example, I have a test.txt file that says:

Name: test

Applicat: something

Date: today

My current code would find the word "Applicat," and replace it with "Applicat: ft_link," but the "something" is still there.  How can I make it look like this:

Name: test

Applicat: ft_link

Date: today

?

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the main part of my code:

```
 char buffer[512];
 while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL)
 {

 static const char text_to_find[] = "Applicat:";

 static const char text_to_replace[] = "Applicat: ft_link";

 char *pos = strstr(buffer, text_to_find);
 if (pos != NULL)
 {

 char *temp = calloc(
 strlen(buffer) - strlen(text_to_find) + strlen(text_to_replace) + 1, 1);

 memcpy(temp, buffer, pos - buffer);

 memcpy(temp + (pos - buffer), text_to_replace, strlen(text_to_replace));

 memcpy(temp + (pos - buffer) + strlen(text_to_replace),
 pos + strlen(text_to_find),
 1 + strlen(buffer) - ((pos - buffer) + strlen(text_to_find)));

 fputs(temp, output);

 free(temp);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your output filename is not the same as your input filename

If you are replacing the whole line, then you can simply just write **text_to_replace** to the file with a newline character.

```
char buffer[512];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL)
{
     static const char text_to_find[] = "Applicat:";
     static const char text_to_replace[] = "Applicat: ft_link\n";  // Added newline
     char *pos = strstr(buffer, text_to_find);
     if (pos != NULL)
     {
         fputs(text_to_replace, output);
     }
}
```

Comment: A good answer.  The file should be read line by line though, what if "Applicat:" appears at file position 510?

Comment: From his code, he is reading the file line by line, unless his lines are longer that 512 characters(including newline). fgets() should read only a line unless as I said his lines are longer that the buffer size

Comment: That was quick and easy.  Thank you very much sir @T.V.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind, what if now i want to change more than one line?  I tried just copying another if statement with new "Name" char declared, but it ended up just duplicating a few lines.  SHould i be doing them all in the same if statement?  Thanks.

Comment: You question is somewhat vague, because the current code should replace all lines that contain `Applicat:`. Do you mean you want to replace all lines that contain `Applicat:` and `Name`?